# Clear previous GeoJSON Object

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I am working on an [app](https://repl.it/@upcheezy/nps) where I'm trying to clear out the previous Leaflet GeoJSON layer in favor of the current one. I have tried both `map.removeLayer(geojsonPoint)` and `map.clearLayer(geojsonPoint)` but neither of them seem to work in my function. Here is how I'm trying to work it out:

```
function addPoints(geoJsonMain, responseJson) {
    console.log(geoJsonMain);
    let pointData = L.geoJSON(geoJsonMain);
    for (let j = 0; j < responseJson.data.length; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < geoJsonMain.features.length; i++) {
            // console.log(geoJsonMain.features[i].properties.stateCode);
            if (geoJsonMain.features[i].properties.stateCode !== responseJson.data[j].states) {
                map.removeLayer(pointData)
                // console.log(geoJsonMain.features[i].properties.stateCode, ' ', responseJson.data[j].states)
            } else {
                pointData.addTo(map);
                map.fitBounds(pointData.getBounds());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

but when I have the removeLayer(pointData) in there it doesn't clear anything. Why is it not clearing the current L.geoJSON layer? Please refer to the linked repl.it for the full layout. It is looking for state abbreviations (i.e. NY, NC, SC, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have missed what you're trying to accomplish, but this takes your new points, adds them to the map and clears out the old points.

```
function addPoints(geoJsonMain, responseJson) {
    let pointData = L.geoJSON(geoJsonMain);
    pointData.addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(pointData.getBounds());

    if(oldPoints){
      oldPoints.removeFrom(map);
    }
    oldPoints = pointData;

}
```

oldPoints is a global variable I set to false as a flag to avoid running or throwing an error on the first go. After the first run it will store the old points and clear them each subsequent run.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. thank you very much, sir!